# Probability of having exactly 3 fence posts painted in the same color?

Tags: probability

I had 3-4 ideas on how to solve this problem, but all of them gave me different answers and that is not good, so I would appreciate a solution. Problem:

We are painting a fence from both sides. This fence is made out of 6 posts. Each side of the post is being colored using 3 different kinds of paint. What is the probability of having exactly 3 fence posts painted in the same color (f.e. both sides are blue)?

If it's not too hard, could someone verify that the answers to the following sub-problems are correct?

1) Probability of at least one fence post being painted in the same color?

My answer: $1-\frac{(3*2)^6}{(3*3)^6} = 0.91$

2) Imagine that we are looking at the fence from front and then from the other side. What's the probability that we won't see any adjacent poles of same color?

My answer: $\frac{(3*2^5)^2}{(3^6)^2} = 0.017$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fine for your questions.  For the question of exactly three matching on opposite sides, I assume you would accept one blue on both sides and two others red on both sides.  Under that assumption, the chance a given post is the same color on both sides is $\frac 13$.  The chance exactly three match is $6 \choose 3$ (ways to choose the three that match) $(\frac 13)^3(\frac 23)^3=\frac {160}{729}$